# compare/countNonZero return bigger value then expected

Tags: c++, opencv

If I take 2 binary images (pixel values 0 or 255) and compare them with compare/countNonZero and then with two nested loops I don't get same "score".

So first I use this code:

```
compare(mat1, mat2, mat_tmp, CMP_EQ);

score = countNonZero(mat_tmp);
```

and then this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < mat1.cols; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < mat2.rows; ++y)
    {
        Scalar s1 = mat1.at<uchar>(y,x);
        Scalar s2 = mat2.at<uchar>(y,x);
        score += (s1.val[0]/255)*(s2.val[0]/255);
    }
}
```

and score values are significantly different (e.g. compare/countNonZero score=206 814 and for nested loops is 1022).

Shouldn't it be same? Why is it so? Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't count the ones where both the matrix pixels are 0 while compare/countNonZero does.

To get the same effect through for loop, try this :

```
score = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < mat1.cols; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < mat2.rows; ++y)
    {
        Scalar s1 = mat1.at<uchar>(y,x);
        Scalar s2 = mat2.at<uchar>(y,x);
        score += (s1.val[0] == s2.val[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me one more thing please: is it possible not to count 0 with compare/countNonZero (so I get same score as with nested loops but using compare/countNonZero)? (I can't see it at the moment)

Comment: To answer my own comment: [multiply](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20multiply%28InputArray%20src1,%20InputArray%20src2,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20double%20scale,%20int%20dtype%29)